# MySql INSERT WHERE then SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql

Im trying to insert values into a table where the ID of the row can only be found by performing a SELECT WHERE on another table.  Below is my query:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value) 
VALUES ('editor_review','5') 
WHERE post_id=(SELECT ID from wp_posts 
               WHERE post_title 
              LIKE "%The Honest Kitchen ZEAL Grain Free Gluten Free All Life Stages Dog Food%");
```

Any ideas to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta
    (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    SELECT id, 'editor_review', '5'
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE post_title LIKE '%The Honest Kitchen ZEAL Grain Free Gluten Free All Life Stages Dog Food%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement for that.

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value) 
SELECT colA, colB
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_title 
LIKE "%The Honest Kitchen ZEAL Grain Free Gluten Free All Life Stages Dog Food%"
```

NOTE That the number of columns must match with each other (also their datatypes)